# import GridView DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a gridview with data on a content page.i need to get the datasource of the gridview as a datatable on master page button click.following is my code

```
string DicPageName = Page.GetType().Name;
        GridView gv1;
        DataTable DT;

        if (DicPageName == "dictionaries_abs_aspx")
        {
            gv1 = (GridView)ContentPlaceHolder2.FindControl("GridView1");
            if (gv1 != null)
            {
                if (gv1.Visible)
                {
                    DT = new DataTable();

                    DT = (DataTable)gv1.DataSource;

                }
            }
        }
```

but DT returns null.plz help

Comment: How did you set the data source?

Comment: The datasource of any web-databound control is null on postbacks. You need to query the datasource(for example a database) again if you want it (or store it in the Seession).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned that the code above is located in a button-click event handler. That is always on postbacks.

The datasource of any web-databound control is null on postbacks. You need to query the datasource(for example a database) again if you want it (or store it in the Seession).

Out of interest: why do you need it? Maybe there's a better approach.